# Trying to understand "expected types" and "type.property.schema" properties in Freebase

Tags: rdf, freebase, rdfs

## Property: expected type

> **Definition:** The expected type of the object referred to by this property [[1](http://www.freebase.com/type/property)].

- is **expected type** equalt to **rdfs:range**?
- Is it the most probable type among all other types that the object might have?

---

## Property: type.property.schema

> **Definition:** The link from a property to its underlying type. This forces a
> property to only belong to a single type [[1](http://www.freebase.com/type/property)].

- Is **type.property.schema** equal to **rdfs:domain**?
- What do they mean by the link? and does a property belong to a single type?
- Does it mean that we are now forced to use only one type from`rdfs:domain`?
- I am a little confused because from what I understood, properties can have multiple types right?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a freebase user, so I don't have a lot of context for the Freebase specific parts, here, but I can speak about about possible relationships to

> - is **expected type** equal to **rdfs:range**?
> - is **type.property.schema** equal to **rdfs:domain**?

I'd interpret a description like:

> Definition: The expected type of the object referred to by this property

to mean something weaker than what rdfs:range means.  The rdfs:range property means that you can *infer* that the object of a triple with that property *actually has* the range as a type.  That is, from:

p rdfs:range R

and

x p y

you can *infer* that

y rdf:type R

If you can independently infer that y does *not* have type R, then you have a logical inconsistency.  However, it sounds like with "expected type", you'd just have something "unexpected", but not necessarily a logical inconsistency.  For instance, you might *expect* a price to be stated in some national currency, but it's not *incorrect* to state it in something else, just *unexpected*.

On the other hand, the definition:

> Definition: The link from a property to its underlying type. This forces a property to only belong to a single type

actually does seem like a pretty good match to rdfs:domain.  If you know that something has a value for the property, then the thing with the property must have the specified type.  However, I don't know whether freebase has another object model more akin to a (common) object-oriented programming language, where properties "belong" to classes.  In RDF, properties don't really *belong* to types.

Comment: I'm slightly confused here.  Why are you "answering" a question you know nothing about?

Comment: @TomMorris That question is a bit misleading.  1. Freebase is something that I don't *use*;  that's different from not knowing anything about it.  A number of freebase-related questions are also about the freebase RDF dumps (which aren't always actually legal RDF), and the use of rdfs:domain and rdfs:range here seems to put it in that category.  2. I am a much more active RDF user, and can describe what the meaning of rdfs:domain and rdfs:range is, and how other properties (unless explicitly related to them) could differ in their semantics.

Comment: @TomMorris All that said, I've prefixed my question with a bit more about the scope;  I'm aiming to address the relationships to rdfs:domain and rdfs:range.

Comment: While the answer represents a plausible guess based on the textual description provided, it doesn't match how the Freebase system operates in the real world.  As such it is misleading and could cause the OP, if they rely on it, to infer incorrect semantics.  In many applications, incorrect semantics are to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`Expected Type` is mostly a social/UI construct.  It influences how the Freebase web UI [used to] guide the user in choosing appropriate link targets, but if one were to write a triple/quad using MQLwrite or one of the bulk upload APIs, it would have no effect whatsoever, so it's not appropriate to rely on it when trying to reason about what was intended.

Similarly, the `type/property/schema` property guides several web UI actions, but only by convention and has no influence on what is or is not allowed at the raw triple level.

Because of the above behaviors, one should be especially carefully about inferring intent from triples which don't match what's shown in the Freebase web client because they're unlikely to have been vetted by many (or any!) people.  "Naked triples" (ie without a corresponding asserted type), would-be topics without the type `/common/topic` asserted, and a variety of other corner cases should all be view askance when attempting to infer intent.

To answer some of the sub-questions:

- Yes, a property "belongs" to a single type (although, as described above, it's a very weak belonging relationship).  You can see this from the schema page by the italic *unique* next to the property description
- No, a property can't "belong" to multiple types (see above about uniqueness)
- No, rdfs:range and rdfs:domain are not equivalent to the given Freebase properties, for the reasons described above.

Comment: This adds good information about the freebase context, but it doesn't seem to address the parts about the relationship to to rdf:domain and rdfs:range ("is expected type equalt to rdfs:range?", "Is type.property.schema equal to rdfs:domain?").

Comment: I have to agree with @JoshuaTaylor here... also it rarely helps the quality of an answer to mock other answers (edit proposed).